# Issue while parsing mongo collection which has few schemas in spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm moving data from one collection to another in other cluster using Spark. the data's schema is not consistent(I mean that has few schema's in a single collection with different data types with little variations). When I try to read data from spark, the sampling is unable to get all the schema's of the data and throwing the below error.(I have a complex schema which I can't explicitly mention instead of spark gets by sampling.)

`com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast ARRAY into a NullType (value: BsonArray{values=[{ "type" : "GUEST_FEE", "appliesPer" : "GUEST_PER_NIGHT", "description" : null, "minAmount" : 33, "maxAmount" : 33 }]})`

I tried reading the collection as an RDD and write as an RDD still the issue persists.

Any help on this.!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

All these `com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast SOME_TYPE into a NullType` come from incorrect schema inference. For schema-less data sources such as JSON file or mongodb, Spark does a scan of small fraction of the data to determine the types. If some particular field has lots of NULL's you can get unlucky and type will be set as `NullType`.

One thing you can do is increase the number of entries scanned for schema inference.

Another - get the inferred schema first, fix it, and reload dataframe with fixed schema:

```
def fix_spark_schema(schema):
  if schema.__class__ == pyspark.sql.types.StructType:
    return pyspark.sql.types.StructType([fix_spark_schema(f) for f in schema.fields])
  if schema.__class__ == pyspark.sql.types.StructField:
    return pyspark.sql.types.StructField(schema.name, fix_spark_schema(schema.dataType), schema.nullable)
  if schema.__class__ == pyspark.sql.types.NullType:
    return pyspark.sql.types.StringType()
  return schema

collection_schema = sqlContext.read \
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql") \
    .options(...) \
    .load() \
    .schema

collection = sqlContext.read \
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql") \
    .options(...) \
    .load(schema=fix_spark_schema(collection_schema))
```

In my case all problematic fields could be represented with StringType, you might make the logic more complex if needed.

Comment: How do you increase the number of entries scanned for schema inference?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem:
* either Spark incorrectly detected your schema and considered some fields as required (`nullable = false`) - in such case, you can still define it explicitly and set `nullable` to true. It would work if your schema was evolving and in some time in the past you added or removed a field but still keeping column type (e.g. String will be always a String and not a Struct or other completely different type)
* or your schemas are completely inconsistent, i.e. your String field transformed at some time to a Struct or other completely different type. In such case I don't see other solution than use `RDD` abstraction and work with very permissive types as `Any` in Scala (`Object` in Java) and using `isInstanceOf` tests to normalize all fields into a 1 common format

Actually I see also another possible solution, but only if you know what data has which schema. For instance, if you know that for data between 2018-01-01 and 2018-02-01 you use schema#1 and for the others schema#2, you can write a pipeline that will transform schema#1 to schema#2. Later you could simply `union` both datasets and apply your transformations on consistently structured values.

---

Edit:

I've just tried similar code you give and it worked correctly on my local MongoDB instance:

```
val sc = getSparkContext(Array("mongodb://localhost:27017/test.init_data")) 

// Load sample data
import com.mongodb.spark._

val docFees =
  """
    | {"fees": null}
    | {"fees": { "main" : [ { "type" : "misc", "appliesPer" : "trip", "description" : null, "minAmount" : 175, "maxAmount" : 175 } ]} }
  """.stripMargin.trim.stripMargin.split("[\\r\\n]+").toSeq
MongoSpark.save(sc.parallelize(docFees.map(Document.parse)))

val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)
rdd.saveToMongoDB(WriteConfig(Map("uri"->"mongodb://localhost:27017/test.new_coll_data", "replaceDocument"->"true")))
```

And when I checked the result in MongoDB shell I got:

```
> coll = db.init_data; 
test.init_data
> coll.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b33d415ea78632ff8452c60"), "fees" : { "main" : [ { "type" : "misc", "appliesPer" : "trip", "description" : null, "minAmount" : 175, "maxAmount" : 175 } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b33d415ea78632ff8452c61"), "fees" : null }
> coll = db.new_coll_data;
test.new_coll_data
> coll.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b33d415ea78632ff8452c60"), "fees" : { "main" : [ { "type" : "misc", "appliesPer" : "trip", "description" : null, "minAmount" : 175, "maxAmount" : 175 } ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b33d415ea78632ff8452c61"), "fees" : null }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  I tried with rdd's too and it is still failing on the same issue. any ideas?

Comment: Please post your code and add some examples of problematic values. It would help me to try to help you ;)

Comment: `val customRdd = MongoSpark.load(sparkSession, ReadConfig(Map("uri"->"mongodb://username:pwd@mongo--motst-:27017/db.collection")))
   customRdd.saveToMongoDB(WriteConfig(Map("uri"->"mongodb://username:pwd@mongo--motst-:27017/db1.collection1","replaceDocument"->"true")))`

Comment: let's say the field fees and it has the below scenarios:
doc1: fees: null(of null type)
doc2: "fees" : {
            "main" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "misc",
                    "appliesPer" : "trip",
                    "description" : null,
                    "minAmount" : 175,
                    "maxAmount" : 175
                }
            ]}

Comment: Thanks. I've just updated my answer with code snippet.  I hope it helps you a little.

Comment: I see what you are doing here. At the source when I'm sampling the null value is taken of the type NULLTYPE and the other documents has of the type ARRAY. I think that's the difference we have between our use cases. But thanks for trying.